# Using ng-model on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a template which creates an input element dynamically on runtime. I want to capture the data entered into this input element into my model. I am trying to achieve this using ng-model. However, its not working. On inspecting the element, I see that correct expression has been binded to ng-model, but it is not updating my model. Here is my code:

Template:

```
<div child-ng-model="userReg.candidateData.PrimarySkills">
   <!-- this div creates an input element on runtime -->
</div>
```

Directive:

```
(function (window) {
  'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp.userRegistration.directive')
    .directive('childNgModel', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                childNgModel: '@'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var el = element.children().eq(0);
                el.attr('ng-model', scope.childNgModel);
                $compile(el)(scope);
            }
        }
    }]);
})(window);
```

You can see the correct value being assigned to ng-model below:
[image: ng-model binding]

The text I enter in the input field is not getting captured by my model (userReg.candidateData.PrimarySkills). Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating an isolated scope in your directive. Thus, the ngModel cannot write to the outer scope variable.

Try the following:

```
(function (window) {
  'use strict';

   angular.module('myApp.userRegistration.directive')
    .directive('childNgModel', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true, // create a normal child scope
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var el = element.children().eq(0);
                el.attr('ng-model', attrs.childNgModel); // just get the attribute value
                $compile(el)(scope);
            }
        }
    }]);
})(window);
```

Comment: Thanks. There is one more minor unrelated issue :) When I console.log my candidateData object, I don't see all the properties in chrome dev tool window. Some properties are clipped by '...' at the end. Even after clicking the arrow which expands the object, I don't see all properties. Any way to fix this? Here is the link: https://s18.postimg.org/4bv9c1r7d/Untitled2.png

Comment: @dk49 This makes the directive directly dependant on the controller and is bad practice. (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom see the green note above this paragraph)

Comment: @gyc There is no dependency. The (name of) the model is passed to the directive, therefore the directive can be used with any controller.

Comment: @gyc, zeroflagL is right. The name 'myApp.userRegistration.directive' is basically a module to which I have attached my directive. The naming convention might have confused you. We are basically following a very modular pattern, wherein every directive/controller/servie is registered under a separate module. To identify the hierarchy, we follow the 'appModuleName.featureModuleName.directive/controller/service' naming convention. This pattern allows extensive re-usability of directives, controllers ans services throughout the app across different modules.

Comment: Your directive has the same name as the scope variable inside the directive "childNgModel". This is bad practice. You and zeroflagL are free to follow or not good practice. This is not my business anymore. thanks. (you have all the links you need and a correct answer (zeroflagL's or mine are correct))

Answer (score 0):

The model is not available inside the directive.

You have to establish two-way binding first:

```
scope: {
  childNgModel: '='
```

The change the model of the input to `childNgModel`:

```
el.attr('ng-model', "childNgModel");
$compile(el)(scope);
```

Now the input updates `childNgModel` inside the directive, which itself is linked to `userReg.candidateData.PrimarySkills` outside teh directive.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a model as an interpolated string using '@'.

Try with '=' instead.

If you want the interpolated string contained in the model, you need to surround it with `{{ child-ng-model="userReg.candidateData.PrimarySkills" }}`

However, using the same name for the directive and the model in the directive is bad practice. You'd better create an attribute especially for the model.

```js
function MyController() {
  this.userReg = {candidateData: {PrimarySkills:["123", "456", "789"]}};
}
function childNgModel($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      value: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.value);
    }
  }
}

angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app')
  .controller('MyController', MyController)
  .directive('childNgModel', childNgModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <div child-ng-model value="ctrl.userReg.candidateData.PrimarySkills">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR this

```js
function MyController() {
  this.userReg = {candidateData: {PrimarySkills:["123", "456", "789"]}};
}
function childNgModel($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      value: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.value);
    }
  }
}

angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app')
  .controller('MyController', MyController)
  .directive('childNgModel', childNgModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <div child-ng-model value="{{ctrl.userReg.candidateData.PrimarySkills}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"using the same name for the directive and the model in the directive is bad practice"_ So according to your opinion `ng-model="foo"` should be `ng-model value="foo"`. Why exactly?

Comment: No, your directive shouldn't have the same name as the attribute you bind to scope. It's confusing. You can call the directive "myDirective" and the model ng-model.

Comment: The directive is called `ngModel` and we cannot rename it because it's built-in. And you say it's bad design and confusing, but nobody ever had a problem with it. You still did not explain the reasoning behind your opinion.

Comment: @zeroflagL What are you talking about? You seem very confused. childNgModel is HIS directive and a scope variable bound to it at the same time. This is bad practice. ng-model is an angular directive of course you cannot change it. Where do you see a reference to ng-model here??

Comment: You wrote _"using the same name for the directive and the model in the directive is bad practice"_. `ngModel` does exactly that. So according to you, `ngModel` is badly designed. And you still did not explain why it is bad practice.

Comment: @zeroflagL can you verify your facts before you harrass people in the comments section? https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js Tell me where does it bind an ngModel variable to the scope? Thanks.

Comment: @zeroflagL besides, yes, the official angular source CAN be badly designed. (what's with the use of 'clazz' instead of 'class' because it's a reserved word? please...